# rxJava error catching socketTimeoutException

Tags: android, error-handling, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I have an observable generated from retrofit that I am trying to implement error handling for, specifically connection timeouts. The subscribers on error gets called just fine but the app still crashes with a sockettimeout error. Any advice?

```
Observable<History> history = api.returnHistoryRX(pair, String.valueOf(unixTime-3600), String.valueOf(unixTime));

history.onErrorReturn(throwable -> null);
```

subscriber

```
public void getPriceNow(Observable<List<history>> history, String pair) {
        Timestamp timestamp2;
        timestamp2 = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());


        history.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(history1 -> {
                    String currentValue;

                    if (history1.size()>0){
                        System.out.println("testing rx");

                    }
                }, e->System.out.println("getPriceNow: error called"));
    }
```

To Test I am setting the timeout to something unreasonably low with okhttp

```
    private  OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

The error chain looks like this:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.

Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: failed to connect

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke `history.onErrorReturn(...)`, that method returns a **new** `Observable` with the appropriate behavior applied. You'll need to use that returned observable where you want the error handling behavior applied. In your case it might be as simple as changing

```
history.onErrorReturn(throwable -> null);
```

to

```
history = history.onErrorReturn(throwable -> null);
```

or moving it to where you initialize your `history` variable.

Comment: This is 100% correct. I actually found the crash wasn't happening due to these calls but elsewhere in the app making the same calls. After I removed the bit causing the crash I still had the issue of the onErrorReturn not firing off and making this update fixed that completely. Without this I probably would have been staring at the same bit for hours so thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

add  .onExceptionResumeNext {

on observer

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up gloable error handler

// If Java 8 lambdas are supported
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(e -> { });

// If no Retrolambda or Jack
RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler(Functions.emptyConsumer());